# Can I install a ceiling light fixture on a wall, say a closet

Tags: walls, light-fixture, ceiling

I bought a small flush ceiling mount fixture, can I install it on a closet wall?

Comment: Most times it is only a design name between ceiling or wall difference, but there could be other conditions.  If you have a power cable in the wall, it should be possible, if you will be happy with direction the light is showing.

Comment: Is this a standard Edison-bulb fixture, or a fixture with an integrated (LED) emitter?

Comment: What country are we talking about? Building code can vary.

Comment: Pictures of the fixture and the junction box you want to attach the fixture to.

Answer (score 2):

**Incandescent luminaires are NOT permitted.**

2020 NEC

410.16 Luminaires in Clothes Closets.

(C) Location. The minimum clearance between luminaires installed in clothes closets and **the nearest point of a closet storage space shall be as follows:**

(1) 300 mm (12 in.) for surface-mounted incandescent or LED luminaires with a completely enclosed light source installed on the wall above the door or on the ceiling.

(2) 150 mm (6 in.) for surface-mounted fluorescent luminaires installed on the wall above the door or on the ceiling.

(3) 150 mm (6 in.) for recessed incandescent or LED luminaires with a completely enclosed light source installed in the wall or the ceiling.

(4) 150 mm (6 in.) for recessed fluorescent luminaires installed in the wall or the ceiling.

(5) Surface-mounted fluorescent or LED luminaires shall be permitted to be installed within the closet storage space where identified for this use.

(6) LED luminaires with a completely enclosed light source or fluorescent luminaires shall be permitted to be installed within the area defined in 410.2 Exception.

https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=3553.0

---

410.2 Definition.

Closet Storage Space. The volume bounded by the sides and back closet walls and planes extending from the closet floor vertically to a height of 1.8 m (6 ft) or to the highest clothes-hanging rod and parallel to the walls at a horizontal distance of 600 mm (24 in.) from the sides and back of the closet walls, respectively, and continuing vertically to the closet ceiling parallel to the walls at a horizontal distance of 300 mm (12 in.) or the width of the shelf, whichever is greater; for a closet that permits access to both sides of a hanging rod, this space includes the volume below the highest rod extending 300 mm (12 in.) on either side of the rod on a plane horizontal to the floor extending the entire length of the rod. See Figure 410.2.

Exception: Where a shelf is not present in the area of wall above the closet’s entrance opening or doorway extending from the top of such opening or doorway vertically to the ceiling, including the area of ceiling extending perpendicular from the area of wall directly above the closet’s entrance opening or doorway to a horizontal distance of 300 mm (12 in.), shall not be defined as closet storage space. See Figure 410.2

[image]

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PDUI1hif0XcJ:https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/Course-GetQuestion.php%3FQID%3D3552.0%26qnum%3D32+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-1-d